# Possible to group several 'Like" results for SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to wrap my head around using the `Like` operator in SQL Server 2005 to see if I can use several statements and group the results.

For example I have millions of email addresses but need to filter them by domains (`@yahoo`, `@hotmail`, etc.)

I can return one domain but when trying to do multiple I getting issues.

So I am looking to query a database using multiple like statements but grouping them by the domains.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Filter or Group?  You've used both terms interchagably

Comment: What issues are you getting?  What the result of such query should look like?

Comment: why don't you place the these domain in a table and then go for like.

Comment: Sorry if I miscommunicated. What I meant is filtering the domains such as yahoo, hotmail, etc but then have them all grouped together to get a count on each.

So that all of hotmail domains are together and can yield me a total as well as the others. I can do it for each domain separate but doing it will require a lot of work and I am thinking doing it all within one query would make it easier. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `or`?

```
where email like '%@yahoo.com' or
      email like '%@hotmail.com'
```

Comment: Just a word of warning: using the leading `%` of course will make sure no indices can be used, which could lead to rather bad performance characteristics when searching in *millions of email addresses*

Comment: @marc_s - You will still need an **expression** of some sort to isolate the domain, won't you?

Answer (score 0):

Since you use both `FILTER` and `GROUP` here's examples of each:

Filter:

```
select 
    email, 
    SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('@',email)+1,LEN(email)) Domain
FROM Email
WHERE SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('@',email)+1,LEN(email))  
    IN('yahoo.com','hotmail.com')
```

Ordering:

```
select 
    email, 
    SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('@',email)+1,LEN(email)) Domain
FROM Email
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('@',email)+1,LEN(email))
```

Grouping:

```
select 
    SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('@',email)+1,LEN(email)) Domain,
    COUNT(*)
FROM Email
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('@',email)+1,LEN(email))
```